# Button not calling a controller in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a screen where a user can select differente kinds of plans for his account. Like this:

```
#plans
 <% Plan.all.order(:amount).each do |plan| %>
     <%= render 'shared/plan_detail', {plan: plan, button_text: 'Choose this' } %>
 <% end %>

 #plan_detail
 <div class="plan-details">
    <header class= <%= plan.css %> >
      <h3><%= plan.name %></h3>
      <small><%= plan.visibility %></small>      
      <p><%= plan.card_description.html_safe %></p>
      <span class="plan-price"><sup>$</sup><%= plan.amount.to_s %></span>
    </header>
    <article>
     <%= plan.features_description.html_safe %>
      <%= link_to button_text,  {:controller => "accounts", :action => "update_plan", :plan => plan.id }, title: button_text, :class=>"btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-green dialog-open" %>
    </article>
 </div><!-- end plan details -->
```

And In my controller i have:

```
#accounts_controller.rb
def update_plan
  @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan])
  current_user.plan = @plan
  current_user.save
end
```

My routes its like this

```
  get '/account/plans', to: 'accounts#plans', as: :update_plan
  put '/account/plans', to: 'accounts#update_plan'
```

But I click on the button, and nothing happens. What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you get any error? What is the log generated when you click on the link?

Comment: Nothing happens. The page keep on the same state, and the server doesnt run any controller. Do I need to put this on a form?

Comment: There should be something appeared in the server log when you click on the link. Can you post it in the question?

Comment: If I put the url directly in the browser and presse enter, it runs the method 'plans' of my controller. and runs ok. 

https://localhost/account/plans?plan=2

But if i press the button (and it shows the right url on that, when viewing the code), nothing happens. Theres nothing being called on the server side

Comment: Perhaps you have some JavaScript that is running `preventDefault()` that you don't know about. Have you tried removing all the classes from the button to make sure there isn't a class that's triggering unwanted behavior?

Comment: I guess the problem is in my routes. I will add it to the question

Comment: You would get server logs and a routing error if that were the case. Something is preventing your link from firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long shot, but seeing that your link has `dialog-open` I wouldn't be surprised if there was some Javascript preventing your link from working. In order to debug this further I would

a) Check browser's Javascript console for any errors

b) Remove the `dialog-open` class to see what happens

Comment: Perfect Marcin. Thank you